# how get my url in this ajax? i have a function but dont know how use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this is my function :

```
functiohtml(i18n.tr(html));
        $("#rpps").focus();}
      })
    }
```

i want to use it here in my code instead of repeating myseld

```
function forgotten() {
    if (force_mssa
```

so my question is how i replace it and get the right Url for each ?????????????

Comment: if (blah blah){ 
  ajaxRequest("theUrl");
} else { ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator in the url\

```
index_content.php?mode=physician&panel=forgotten&force_mssante="
+ (login_physician_choice == "extern" ? "1" : "0")
```

it should look like this :

```
function forgotten() {
    if (force_mssante_for_externals) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index_content.php?mode=physician&panel=forgotten&force_mssante=" + (login_physician_choice == "extern" ? "1" : "0") + ",
            success: function (html) {
                $(".panel-body").html(i18n.tr(html));
                $("#rpps").focus();
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first case you sould use `mode=physician&panel=forgotten&force_mssante=0`,
at the second case you should use `mode=physician&panel=forgotten&force_mssante=1`.
You should pass as argument `GETQuery` the text after the `?`.
More from GET queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams